# Unable to scan Outlook Attachment for encryption

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I am trying to detect an encrypted attachment using **ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib**,
but the code breaks while debugging on this line:

`FileStream fileStreamIn = new FileStream(attachtype, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

Is there any other way through which I can get Outlook attachment and scan for encryption?

```
if (attachments.Count != 0)           
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= mail.Attachments.Count; i++)
    {                       
        String attachtype = mail.Attachments[i].FileName.ToLower();

        if (extensionsArray.Any(attachtype.Contains))
        {                   
            FileStream fileStreamIn = new FileStream(attachtype, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);                            
            ZipInputStream zipInStream = new ZipInputStream(fileStreamIn);
            ZipEntry entry = zipInStream.GetNextEntry();
            MessageBox.Show("IsCrypted: " + entry.IsCrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `... but the code breaks while debugging on this line:` And what is the exception (and or message) you are getting?

Comment: It says Source not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespaces.

According to the MSDN the Filename property does the following ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.filename.aspx)):

> Returns a String (string in C#) representing the file name of the
>   attachment. Read-only.

So the value is only the name of the file, not the location (it does not exist on disk as a accessible file). When supplying just the filaneme into a `FileStream` it will attempt to open a file with that name in the local directory (which probably does not exist).

---

It seems from the documentation you'll need to store it using the `SaveAsFile` method ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.saveasfile.aspx)) into a temporary file and load a `FileStream` from that.

So something like:

```
// Location to store file so we can access the data.
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
try {
    // Save attachment into our file
    mail.Attachments[i].SaveToFile(tempFile);

    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(tempFile)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
} finally {
    // Cleanup the temp file
    File.Delete(tempFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this saved my day!